# Why does my Android app START VERY SLOW on REAL devices but normal on emulator?

Tags: android, performance, startup

First of all, the main content of the app runs really fast on both. The problem is, as the title says, it starts very slow in the real device I tested it in, but starts fast on emulator. It takes about 2-4 seconds of delay before the activity shows which is just way too much.

I reviewed my code and I don't see any problem. I even tinkered the onCreate, onResume, etc. methods but to no avail.

Here are some details:

- Min SDK: 16
- Emulators' SDKs: 17, 18, 21 (I tested the app on these three)
- Real device: Xperia Z - Lollipop

... and the app's details:

- uses many external libraries (from github mostly)
- uses RTL language (Arabic), but is not rendered on startup
- I suspect this is related to this:
  ([Android app working on emulator but not on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248152/android-app-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device))
- additional related problem: the app's state is not saved after I go out of the app and then back (but I saw somewhere that this is normal and not a bug).

I won't share the code here because the app is too large and complex, and besides I don't think that the code is the problem since it's super fast after startup.

Here are the libraries I used:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0'
compile 'com.guerwan:transitionbackport:1.1'
compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.1'

compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'

compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'

compile 'asia.ivity.android:drag-sort-listview:1.0'

compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'

compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'
```