# Media Player Crashes on Real Device Android

Tags: android, listview, media-player, android-tv, kodi

I have a songs in list view which i am getting it from json service. I have a play button, Facebook and Twitter Share Button on every row. When i click on play button song starts and seek bar & Fb Twitter sharing also working Fine. Its working fine on emulator and as well as in mobile.
But i am developing this app for android TV, & in Android TV when i click on Play and Share Button everything crashes, TV and my mobile has same API version. Please Help.

I hear about androidSupportrTl:true ? is this working for this issue  ?

When i click on play button On Tv No error found 
Log Cat :

```
01-10 07:13:33.501 17284-17293/luck.materialdesign.tabsnavigator I/art: Thread[5,tid=17293,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xab8d8600,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
01-10 07:13:34.273 17284-17293/luck.materialdesign.tabsnavigator I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: can you please post code and error log here so can we solve issue

Comment: bro from where i put error log?? because its fine working on emulator and mobile device, It crashes on TV.. while clicking on Play Button.

Answer (score 0):

[`android:supportsRtl="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) only means that if you set `supportsRtl true`, your layout will be mirrored from right to left. So you do not have to create special layout for it. It just declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left (RTL) layouts.

> If set to true and [`targetSdkVersion`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) is set to 17 or higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts. If set to false or if [`targetSdkVersion`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your layouts will always be left-to-right).
>
> The default value of this attribute is `false`.

This might be because of your layout. According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248152/android-app-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device), you need to fix your layout accordingly. Make sure that the API version you are using is supported in your Android TV.