# My android app running successfully in emulator but after building apk file it wont run on any mobile

Tags: android, xml

Hello every one here i am developing an android app based on rest services it's working fine on emulator.
but after building an apk file it wont run in any mobile.

Here is **Menifest.xml**  code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lenovo.weblogin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity"></activity>
    </application>

 </manifest>
```

Please help me anyone my app is almost over but it is not working in real device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248152/android-app-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device

Comment: how are you running your app to phone by using debugging by usb or any other source.

Comment: or have u make build frome menu build-> Build APK(s)?

Comment: I am running by building apk

Comment: it is working fine on nougat but it is not working on remaining versions please help me

Comment: could you post  your logcat here @sathish

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: min SDK version 17